# How to reload firewalld without loosing Libvirt iptables forwarding rules

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, firewalld, nftables

It's been well know that firewalld will flush Libvirt rules upon reload and thus making port forwarding to VMs broken until you restart libvirtd. Here is what I did:

1. Create `/etc/systemd/system/firewalld-reload-hook.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=firewalld reload hook - run a hook script on firewalld reload
Wants=dbus-broker.service
After=dbus-broker.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/bin/busctl monitor --system --json=short --match "interface=org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1,member=Reloaded" | while read -r line ; do [ -x /sbin/firewalld-reload-hook ] && /sbin/firewalld-reload-hook ; done'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Create `/sbin/firewalld-reload-hook`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Invoked by /etc/systemd/system/firewalld-reload-hook.service
set -e

logger "$BASH_SOURCE: Firewalld reload hook triggered."

/usr/bin/systemctl restart libvirtd

logger "$BASH_SOURCE: Libvirt restarted."

exit 0
```

and make it executable `chmod +x /sbin/firewalld-reload-hook`

3. Install `libvirt-hook-qemu`

```
git clone https://github.com/saschpe/libvirt-hook-qemu.git
make install
```

4. Edit `/etc/libvirt/hooks/hooks.json` to match your needs. This just an example

```
{
    "www": {
        "private_ip": "192.168.122.100",
        "port_map": {
            "tcp": [80, 443]
        }
    },
    "mail": {
        "private_ip": "192.168.122.101",
        "port_map": {
            "tcp": [25, 465]
        }
    }
}
```

5. Enable and start `firewalld-reload-hook.service`

```
systemctl enable firewalld-reload-hook.service
systemctl start firewalld-reload-hook.service
```

6. `firewall-cmd --reload`

At this point `systemctl restart libvirtd` and `firewall-cmd --reload` produce the same results and survive reboots (tested on Debian bullseye with nftables and libvirt 7.0/NAT network)

So, is this the best way of doing it?

Refer
[libvirt-hook-qemu](https://github.com/saschpe/libvirt-hook-qemu), [firewalld-reload-hook.service](https://gist.github.com/patrickwbarnes/c1dce088e3396d4f3ceacd3312c2248b), [firewalld.dbus](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.dbus.html)